# Output of variable content in "catch" exception block in Jenkins Groovy DSL pipeline

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have the next workable part of code in my `Jenkins` pipeline:

```
saltnodes.each {
        node('slave1') {
            stage('Salt call') {
                saltresult = salt authtype: 'pam', clientInterface: runner(
                        function: 'state.orch', mods: 'test.deploy', pillarvalue: "$someParams"),
                        credentialsId: 'mycreds', servername: "http://$it"
                println JsonOutput.prettyPrint(saltresult)
            }
        }
```

In this part of code I am trying to implement `"try"` and `"catch"` exception handler:

```
import groovy.transform.Field

saltnodes.each {
        node('slave1') {
            stage('Salt call') {
              try{
                @Field result = salt authtype: 'pam', clientInterface: runner(
                        function: 'state.orch', mods: 'test.deploy', pillarvalue: "$someParams"),
                        credentialsId: 'mycreds', servername: "http://$it"
                  }
              catch (e){
                  def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
                  println jsonSlurper.parseText(result)
            }
        }
```

But when I use `@Filed` transformation here, I get `"Null pointer exception"`

How else can I pass `"result"` variable to `"catch"` block in order to print content of result variable there?

Comment: You can define it before the `try` block. In `catch` you need to check if it's set (not null). AFAIR `@Field` is for global script fields.

Comment: You mean define an empty variable before try block?

Comment: @Opal, I it will not work since it will not print error content of  result variable. Without try catch block, content is being printed fine. I need to get error content of result variable.

Comment: is that command failing job if you do not catch the error ? if not , you do not need try catch at all

Comment: Yes, it fails but it also prints the output of result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to figure it out. 
The problem was that I understood error output wrongly. An output during error was raising excepetion but not variable content.

As a result I did the next:

```
saltnodes.each {
        node('slave1') {
            stage('Salt call') {
              try{
                  result = salt authtype: 'pam', clientInterface: runner(
                        function: 'state.orch', mods: 'test.deploy', pillarvalue: "$someParams"),
                        credentialsId: 'mycreds', servername: "http://$it"
                  println result
                  }
              catch (com.waytta.SaltException e){
                  def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
                  println jsonSlurper.parseText(e.getMessage())
            }
        }
```